# Ionic native http get request fails on ios device (works on android)

Tags: ios, cordova, http, ionic-framework

I'm having some problems with an ionic application on ios. Everytime I try to make a get request to a server on ios, it fails but it works fine on android.

The code for the get is the following:

```
this.http.get(url, {}, {})
  .then(data => {
     // rest of the code
  })
  .catch(error => {

    // Alert for when the url failed
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: "Failed to connect",
      buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    alert.present();

  });
```

with url being a string looking like: https://website.com/script.php?EmployeeID=1

I added allow-navigation to my config.xml file when searching online for my problem like this:
`<allow-navigation href="*" />`

I followed every instructions in https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/ but it still doesn't work. Anyone got any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: what does it show if you log error object?

Comment: @SurajRao If I do a console.log(error); and look through it in XCode, I just get something like: {"status": "-1"}

Comment: is CORS implemented correctly in your API?

Comment: @SurajRao I saw this comment a couple of time and am not sure what it means. Do you mean in my config.xml file or on the server that I try to access?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS also why IOS? https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/#xhr-requests-do-not-work

Comment: your server side response headers

Comment: @SurajRao I'm not the one who programmed the backend so I'll check with him to make sure it's implemented correctly. The application will have to run on iPhone that's why IOS. Also, I ran the application on my Oneplus 3 android device and it works fine. It's when I try on a iPhone that it doesn't. Would a bad implemented CORS still work on android?

Comment: Android doesnt enforce CORS currently.. IOS uses WkWebview which does. Also you need to whitelist localhost:8080 in your config.xml

Comment: @SurajRao Perfect, that must be it then. I'll whitelist localhost:8080 and contact the programmer who did the backend. Thank you very much for your time. I'll mark this as answered.